# How can I pinpoint the origin of an uncaught error in javascript (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting an

> Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'ive/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/splash-2.png'
>         at Error (native)

Of course that path is wrong, so `no such file or directory` makes sense, but for the life of me I can't find where it's getting this path from. I'm also surprised there is no file name and line number there. I'm thinking a full stack trace would be very helpful in finding where this wrong path is being created.

I tried adding

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error('Caught exception: ' + err, err.stack)
  throw err
})
```

to my script, but the stack trace just points me to the `throw` statement, so it's basically useless. Is there any other way to find the source of this mysterious wrong path?

Comment: So your code doesn't reference splash-2.png anywhere?

Comment: yes, but everywhere my code references `splash-2.png`, it does so with a correct, full, absolute path (starting with `/Users/...`)

Comment: The error seems to say different though,

Comment: Are you sure the leading slash is appropriate in all places?

Comment: @MikeCheel How else would I specify an absolute path?

Comment: I'm just saying things like this tend to be something overlooked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is correct as I don't intend to care about Windows users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95191/discussion-between-shawn-and-mike-cheel).